# start solrserver deployed inside tomcat from within eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-mvc, solr

I am working in windows 7 machine.I want to implement search using apache solr with hbase ta
bles as datasource. I have configured apache solr 4.3.1 in tomcat 7. I can able to deploy it successfully by manually starting tomcat server.

When i try to start solr server from within spring mvc web application it says solrserver started,but when i query the solr its giving the following without any errors:

> page 0 of 0 containing UNKNOWN instances

As per my research on solr, it is mentioned embedded solrserver is unfit for production so i need to have httpsolrserver.

So somebody help me clear my head and give me some solution...
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

For production, you would be better with hosting Solr as a seperate instance.
This would keep the responsibility separate, web application and search engine.
Indexing process are resource intensive and would the web application behavior as well.
This can be catered by Master Slave arch, providing best search performance.
External instance can be scaled at will and would not impact the web application.

Comment: thanks jayendra! i am new to solr concept.i hope i have separate solr instance running but still i cant figure out where am going wrong clearly.could you explain me with some examples??